# OCaml-Exception: control execution flow to decrease memory usage

Tags: exception, ocaml

```
let rec remove x = function
    y :: l when x = y -> l
  | y :: l (* x <> y *) -> y :: remove x l
  | [] -> []
```

The book says this function has a problem: the entire list is copied needlessly when the element is not found. Thus, gives the following improved version.

```
exception Unchanged

let rec remove_inner x = function
    y :: l when x = y -> l
  | y :: l -> y :: remove_inner x l
  | [] -> raise Unchanged

let remove x l =
  try remove_inner x l 
  with Unchanged -> l
```

I do not quite understand the point here.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically just a toy example to show why you might want to use exceptions, so there's no need to go too deeply into it.

To understand the point, you just have to realize that lists take up space. So, two copies of a list will take up twice the space of a single list. But in a functional language like OCaml, lists are immutable. Since a list can't be modified, there's no detectable difference between a list and a copy of the list. So you can save space without changing the meaning of the program in any way if you use the same list in two places rather than actually copying the list.

The code you show does this trick when asked to remove an element that's not there. The result will be the same as the input, and the code makes sure the result is identical to the input (not a copy) in that case.

Note that the space saving comes from avoiding the copy, not from the exception per se. But this code is nice and tight when the lists aren't too long.

I hope this helps.

(Side node: in OCaml you can actually detect the difference between the two lists using the `==` operator. This is why people often avoid using this operator; it compromises the functional purity of the language. You definitely want to be careful with it.)

Answer (score 0):

The expression `y :: remove x l` is where the copying occurs.  That's because `::` is the built-in [infix operator] constructor for list elements.

In the naïve version of the `remove` function, the `::` operator is used to construct a new list that has all the elements of the original list except the first one equivalent to the `x` argument.  If the original list had no such elements, then it will still create the new list, and it will be a copy that is equivalent to the original list.

The "improved" version of the `remove` function calls another function `remove_inner` that raises an `Unchanged` exception when it reaches the end of the original list without having removed an element.  The outer `remove` function then returns the original list if it catches the `Unchanged` exception.